# Scroll View not working in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, scroll, android-alertdialog

Somehow the scroll view is not working . The message alert dialog box is showing is really big and so I need to implement vertical scrollbar. I tried  to get data from previous asked question but it isn't solving my issue please help.

I need to show the alert dialog on button click event.

```
 benefits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(Panchgavya.this).create();
                ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
                ad.setMessage(getString(R.string.benefits));
                ad.setTitle("Benefits");
                ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                ad.show();
                TextView textView = (TextView) ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

                textView.setScroller(new Scroller(Panchgavya.this));
                textView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


            }
        });
```

My XML File Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Design.Panchgavya"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/Green"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Panchgavya"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@string/panchgavya"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panchgavya_tv_cow_dung"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cow Dung"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panchgavya_tv_cow_urine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Cow Urine"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panchgavya_tv_cow_milk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Cow Milk"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panchgavya_tv_ghee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:text="Ghee"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panchgavya_tv_dahi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:text="Dahi"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/panchgavya_btn_benefits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Benefits"
        android:background="@color/Green"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try with DialogFragment , which will be having a separate layout... Put your scrollable elements inside that

Comment: @Sreehari please can you share an example?

Comment: I have put up my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom layout for your dialog and set any property easily.

For your requirement, Crate a layout for your required Dialog. Put `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` in your textView inside your layout. And `textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`.

You can set custom layout on your by following method.

```
 public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
        text.setText(msg);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <Textview
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:text="@string/dummy_text_"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgClose"/>





    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

// in your java file put below code 
 private void showPopup() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_terms_services, 
null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    TextView txtDescription = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    ImageView imgClose = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    txtDescription.setText(message);


    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

// after than call that showPopup() methos on button click.Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

class extending `DialogFragment` can have UI elements as per your requirement.

```
public class OrderDetailFragment extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog d = getDialog();
        if (d!=null){
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            d.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        }
    }

   public static OrderDetailFragment getInstance(GeneralListDataPojo dataList){
        OrderDetailFragment orderDetailFragment=new OrderDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(DATA, dataList);
        orderDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return orderDetailFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root_view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_detail, container, false);
        GeneralListDataPojo mDataList = getArguments().getParcelable(DATA);//My class which holds data implemented Parcelable

        //population of data from mDataList  

        return root_view;
    }

    void closeDialog(){
        this.dismiss();
    }

}
```

`fragment_order_detail` is having my requirement specific element's (`ScrollView`/`LinearLayouts`/`Buttons` etc)

`GeneralListDataPojo`  is the class which holds data implements Parcelable for transferring data between components

Now you can invoke this `DialogFragment` from your `Fragment` like this. (Im invoking from a `Fragment`. Change the `FragmentManager` retrieval accordingly if you are using from `Activity`)

```
OrderDetailFragment orderDetailFragment=OrderDetailFragment.getInstance((GeneralListDataPojo) responseObj);
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
orderDetailFragment.show(fragmentManager,"OrderDetailFragment");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create The Custom Dialog layout Using Scroll View in your own custom Layout**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        Button click= dialog.findViewById(R.id.click);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: ex:lyout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>